# What happened to AddExportedObject?

Tags: mef

we have source code from a long time ago .NET 2.0 which looks like:

```
DirectoryCatalog catalog =
    new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(applicationDirectory, providersDirectory), providerSubdirectory));
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();
batch.AddPart(this);
batch.AddExportedObject(container);
container.Compose(batch);
```

This has worked fine for years, but after upgrading visual studio and the framework to .NET 4.0, the call to `AddExportedObject` no longer seems to be supported by MEF.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://mef.codeplex.com/discussions/53527),

> While `CompositionBatch` itself does not contain an `AddExportedObject<T>`
>   there is an extension method for it. The extension methods are in the
>   root `System.ComponentModel.Composition` namespace so ensure you are
>   including that in your file's using statements. If you cannot get the
>   extension method to work you can always call the method directly on
>   `AttributedModelServices`.